# How to insert an accent into a sqlite table in android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, diacritics

I am creating a database in Android, all was going nice, but when I was testing the queries retrieving the correct data I've got an error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14126): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

I know that means that there is no data matching the query, but the fact is that I inserted the data by query and it actually has a match. And the same query works with all the codes that doesn't have accents.

These are the queries for inserting the rows.

```
INSERT INTO "codigo" VALUES('A','PEATÓN');
INSERT INTO "codigo" VALUES('B','PEATÓN');
INSERT INTO "codigo" VALUES('C','PEATÓN');
```

So I did a query that gets the values of the field that I was replacing, like this:

```
String selectCode = "select distinct c.tipo from codigo c";
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectCodigo, new String[] {});
      cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
          String codigo= cursor.getString(0);
          codigos.add(codigo);        
          System.out.println(codigo);
          cursor.moveToNext();
        } 
        cursor.close();
      return codigos;
```

And the result was this:

```
10-14 16:40:32.140: I/System.out(13716): PEAT�N
```

I have the text file in the /raw folder and I edited from the Eclipse so I make sure it wasn't the table export I did, but I have the same results.

**This is the code that reads the file:**

```
 public int insertFromFile(SQLiteDatabase db,Context context, int resourceId) throws IOException {
            // Reseting Counter
            int result = 0;
            // Open the resource
            InputStream insertsStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
            BufferedReader insertReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(insertsStream));

            // Iterate through lines (assuming each insert has its own line and theres no other stuff)
            while (insertReader.ready()) {
                String insertStmt = insertReader.readLine();
                db.execSQL(insertStmt);
                result++;
            }
            insertReader.close();

            // returning number of inserted rows
            return result;
        }
```

How could I get that accent working? 
I am using a lot of them, so, replacing the word is not a way out. 
Please help, is the only thing I need to finish this project.

**UPDATE**: 
Had the same problems two more times later. The first I fixed it by working with a .sql file coded in cp1525 and opened it in Eclipse with the default editor and find/replaced the wrong characters.

The last time I've got this error I made it the right way, and found that if you are working with SQLiteManager it imports files encoded in UTF-8 but it export files in ANSI, so I opened the file with Notepad++, change the enconding of the .sql file from ANSI to UTF-8 and it works fine, all the characters were shown fine.

Comment: SQLite always used UTF-8-encoded strings, and the Android libraries automatically convert Java `String`s from/to if needed. What is the encoding of your source code? What encoding does the compiler think it is? What is the encoding of the log file? What encoding does the file viewer think it is?

Comment: The enconding of my source code is UTF-8. I had other text (strings values not in the database) in the app and they're shown with no problems á,é,í,ó,ú and ñ. The log file is also UTF-8, showing the special characters normal. I don't understand your 2nd and last questions: "What encoding does the compiler think it is? What encoding does the file viewer think it is?" Can you be more specific please?

Comment: What happens with `INSERT INTO codigo VALUES('A',CAST(x'50454154C3934E' AS TEXT))`?

Comment: It works! thank you so much. But as I said I have some big strings like this: "No detenerse antes de la línea de parada o antes de las áreas de intersección de calzadas o no respetar el derecho de paso del peatón." Is there another way make this works? or I have to get the code for every string I have ? (they are 281 of this big ones and most of them have accents).

Comment: Are these `INSERT` statements part of your Java source code, or are they read from another file?

Comment: I have a text file in the /raw folder

Comment: Show the code that reads the statements from that file.

Comment: Check the update in the question please! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [InputStreamReader constructor documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream%29) says:

> Constructs a new `InputStreamReader` on the `InputStream` `in`. This constructor sets the character converter to the encoding specified in the "file.encoding" property and falls back to ISO 8859_1 (ISO-Latin-1) if the property doesn't exist.

If the file is encoded in UTF-8, you have to tell the reader this.

Answer (score 0):

in your SQLQueryString just add before

```
PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";
```

example

```
"PRAGMA encoding = \"UTF-8\"; INSERT INTO MYTABLE (mytablefield) VALUES ('value'); "
```